# Android EditText dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I create `EditText` dynamically, but when I click on them to insert data, the keyboard does not open.

```
MaterialEditText ed = new MaterialEditText(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(0, 20, 30, 0);
rlCampi.addView(ed, layoutParams);
```

Comment: MaterialEditText: what version do you use?

Comment: this: https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Comment: @DeboraCarnevali glad to help you :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with this

```
youredittextname.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    youredittextname.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add edit text try this approach :

```
// Pass it an Activity or Context
    EditText myEditText = new EditText(context); 
// Pass two args; must be LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, or an integer pixel value.
    myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(..., ...)); 
    myLayout.addView(myEditText);
```